# IQ question - line of shaded and unshaded boxes

Tags: pattern, visual

I joined the IQ test online, and got stuck on this question. Unfortunately, they just gave me the total score, not the answer on every individual question. So I still have no idea how to solve it or the answer. If any one can give me a hint, I really appreciate it. Thanks

(Here is the [URL for the test](https://www.iq-test.net/free-iq-test.html), question is number 24)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say:

> B (WBB).

Because:

> We have three black squares. They all move each turn, but according to different rules. Block A starts in position 3 and goes left 1 each turn (3,2,1,6,5). Block B starts in position 4 and goes left 1 each turn (4,3,2,1,6). Block C then goes 5,5,6,2,5, as it goes right +0, +1, +2, +3. Blocks A and C now occupy the same position.

Comment: I think it's the only reasonable explanation for this problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I would choose

> [image]

Because

> I found two patterns which ended up in this configuration.  The simplest one is:
>  Label the dark squares 1, 2, 3.  Then 1 always moves left one square, 2 always moves left one square and 3 moves right 0, then 1, then 2, then 3 squares.
>  This is shown in the following:
>  [image]

It doesn't feel like this is the only possible pattern, but perhaps it is the only one that fits one of the possible solutions.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds correct and rational. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that

> There is no **"correct"** answer

As we see in in rows No. 1-4, there are

> Always 3 white squares and 3 black squares

The pattern from row No. 1 to row No. 2 is that

> 2 black squares go to the left

While

> The remaining 1 black square goes to the right

This pattern also applies from row No. 2 to row No. 3, but from row No. 3 to row No. 4,

> The black squares don't move at all

This means that

> The black squares are not supposed to move further as they are all at the end

As such,

> The pattern in row No. 4 should be the same as in row No. 5 
>  This means that there is no correct answer

Another thing that I noticed is that

> The number of black squares are either 1 or 2 while the pattern in rows No. 1-4 all have 3 black squares.

Comment: $(+1)$ for a unique suggestion :P